# Is it possible to use more than one yml-file on a hugo.io page?

Tags: yaml, config, hugo

I started a page using [Hugo.io](http://hugo.io/), GitHub Pages along with the theme [Arcana for Hugo](https://sec.gd/hugo/themes/arcana/). I like the landingpage.yml that came with arcana and I would like to have a second yml-file with a customizable menu position (like the landingpage.yml) while all other files are generated from markdown-files. I got everything to work locally expect the second yml-file. How can I tell hugo to use two yml-files? Thanks for reading and helping

I searched in the documentation for an answer but couldn't find my answer there. I used the command

```
hugo server --debug --verbose -F --disableFastRender
```

and hugo is detecting changes and I can see the results on localhost in my browser. I copied homepage.yml as test.yml in the same directory, so the hugos data directory has now:
/data/homepage.yml
/data/test.yml
inside. I searched my whole installation for homepage.yml, find a place to add my test.yml, but I didn't find anything. I made a new file in the content directory named test.md and wrote down what I found in _index.md like this:

```
---
title: test
menu: main
weight: 12
---
```

I expected to see my test in the menu and when I click on it the contents of test.yml is shown just like homepage.yml does.

Answer (score 0):

> I searched my whole installation for homepage.yml, find a place to add my test.yml, but I didn't find anything.

Line 12 of this file refers to .Site.Data.homepage. That is what you are looking for.

> I expected to see my test in the menu and when I click on it the contents of test.yml is shown just like homepage.yml does.

That is a wrong assumption. They use different code. The homepage uses the index.html in layouts, while the test.md uses the layouts/_default/single.html.